# Python - IndexError: list index out of range - not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my scrap.py code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

website = "https://houston.craigslist.org/search/cta"

uClient = uReq(website)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

soup_html = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
result_html = soup_html.findAll("p", {"class":"result-info"})

filename = "products.csv"

f = open(filename, "w", encoding='utf8')
headers = "car_name, price\n"
f.write(headers)

for container in result_html:   
    carname = container.a.text

    price_container = container.findAll('span', {'class':'result-price'})
    price = price_container[0].text

    f.write(carname + "," + price + "\n")

f.close()
```

On terminal, it works fine however when I loop it, it gives the following error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrap.py", line 23, in <module>
    price = price_container[0].text.splitlines()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP wants to find people to program his task and asks followup question upon every answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below one. It will fetch you all the items and price and handle `IndexError` if there is any.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

response = urlopen("https://houston.craigslist.org/search/cta")
soup_html = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), "html.parser")
for container in soup_html.find_all("p", {"class":"result-info"}):   
    carname = container.find_all("a")[0].text
    try:
        price = container.find_all('span', {'class':'result-price'})[0].text
    except IndexError:
        price = ""
    print(carname,price)
```

I tried to shorten your code to make it look better.

Comment: its short for you but very complexed for me as I am new to Python

Comment: how can I sort results with price?

Comment: Replace this line with the existing `print` statement `print("Car_Name: {}\nPrice: {}\n".format(carname,price))`

Answer (score 1):

This is because some cars just have no price, e.g. [this one](https://houston.craigslist.org/ctd/d/2016-toyota-tacoma-trd-off/6435658866.html). You can put price to `unknown` if there was no price:

```
price_container = container.findAll('span', {'class':'result-price'})
if len(price_container) > 0:
    price = price_container[0].text
else:
    price = 'unknown'
```

Or you could just skip the ones without price so they'll not get written to the file:

```
price_container = container.findAll('span', {'class':'result-price'})
if len(price_container) == 0:
   continue
price = price_container[0].text
```

> How can I sort it by price?

```
results = []
for container in result_html:   
    carname = container.a.text

    price_container = container.findAll('span', {'class':'result-price'})
    if len(price_container) == 0:
        continue

    price = price_container[0].text.strip('$')
    results.append((int(price), carname))

for price, carname in sorted(results):
    f.write("{}, {}\n".format(carname, price))

f.close()
```

Comment: How can I sort results with price?

Comment: @ShahidShabbir: I added this section. But please stop now as you're just asking two guys at the same time doing work for you..

Comment: How could we get contact number and email address which are inside of each item on page?

Comment: as I said: please do the rest yourself, don't ask people here to work for you. If you want to get people to program for you'd normally need to pay them, right?